# React createContext with defult value for use Mobx store

Tags: reactjs, react-context, mobx, use-context, createcontext

i am creating a context to use Mobx store in my React application, by following the example:

```
 const mainStore = new MainStore(); // mobx store instance
    const storeContext = React.createContext(mainStore);
    export const useStores = () => React.useContext<typeof mainStore>(storeContext);
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <storeContext.Provider value={{...mainStore}}>
          <NavigationProvider>
            <Router>
              <App />
            </Router>
          </NavigationProvider>
        </storeContext.Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
```

and in components is used by example:

```
    function App() {
        const { authStore } = useStores();
        const history = useHistory();
      return (<>test{authStore.isLogin}</>)
    }
```

and there are two questions:

question 1: why use the `useStores` construct when I can just call `React.useContext<typeof mainStore>(storeContext);` in any component itself; and just export `storeContext`?

question 2: if, when creating a context, one value is passed to the default value, and another value is passed to the provider value, then which of them will be used by the consumer? something like this...
[image: different context values]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can avoid `useStores` in that case. When there are more imports or the logic increases, it will make sense
2. Value in `storeContext.Provider` will be used, cause you can delcare your provider in any place of your project and get default value from network for instance